# Monocular depth estimation

Tags: deep-learning, computer-vision

I am currently reading the paper [towards robust monocular depth estimation](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1907.01341v3.pdf) and I have 2 doubts about it.

First of all the paper stated that there are 2 types of depth annotated, dense and sparse. What are they and what are their differences?

Secondly, the paper predicts the relative depth given an input, how do we calculate the loss when a relative depth map is predicted? I know we could simply use MSE if the model predicts an absolute depth map. If I were to train a model myself to predict relative depth maps as well, how should I calculate the loss or other evaluation metrics?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance!